# How can i add a telephone field at the time of customer registration form in magento 2?

Tags: forms, magento2.3.1, register

There are an option is required selected
Please go to stores=> configuration => customer configuration and enable mobile number.

So let me know if is there anywhere else I need to change? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create Customer Attribute using a Custom module
Please create a module as follows.

Create **registration.php** in **app/code/Namespace/Module** and add following code.

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Namespace_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

Create **module.xml** in **app/code/Namespace/Module/etc** and add following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Namespace_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Create **InstallData.php** in **app/code/Namespace/Module/Setup** and add following code.

```
<?php


namespace Namespace\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $customerSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'telephone', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Telephone',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'telephone')
        ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]
        ]);
        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Then add followinf code for **Telephone input field** to **app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml**

```
<div class="field required">
    <label for="customer_telephone" class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Telephone')) ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="customer_telephone" id="customer_telephone" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getFormData()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Telephone')) ?>" data-mage-init='{"mage/trim-input":{}}' class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-number':true}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You with a custom field is ok. but there are already in the file so I just need to display. So let me know that solutions.

Comment: The code you see in the registration.phtml file is for address fields, To show that fields on the registration form you have to create a file 
app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_create.xml

And add the following code in body tag


<referenceBlock name="customer_form_register">
            <action method="setShowAddressFields">
                <argument name="show.address.fields" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>

Comment: Yes, you are right but then extra fields also comes. I need to display only telephone field. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want add custom field, in customer account, Now you need to override the register.phtml in your custom theme.

Create custom theme, then create register.phtml in following path

app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/templates/form/register.phtml

Now, copy codes, from module-customer/view/frontend/templates/form/register.phtml and paste to above created file.

Then, add your custom field:

```
<div class="field required">
    <label for="custom_field" class="label"><span><?= __('CustomField') ?></span></label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="custom_field" id="custom_field" value="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCustomField()) ?>" title="<?= __('CustomField') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-phoneStrict':true}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Before doing that, you have to create customer attribute for your custom_field to store the database.

Create the Customer Attribute:

You need to create a custom module to do that, after create Custom Module

Create InstallData.php in following path Vendor\Module\Setup

InstallData.php

In this below code I have added custon_field attribute.

```
<?php

  namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

  use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
  use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
  use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
  use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

  class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
  {

      /**
       * CustomerSetupFactory
       * @var CustomerSetupFactory
       */
      protected $customerSetupFactory;

      /**
       * $attributeSetFactory
       * @var AttributeSetFactory
       */
      private $attributeSetFactory;

      /**
       * initiate object
       * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
       * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
       */
      public function __construct(
          CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
          AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
      )
      {
          $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
          $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
      }

      /**
       * install data method
       * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
       * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
       */
      public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
      {

          /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
          $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

          $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
          $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

          /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
          $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
          $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
          /**
           * customer registration form default field mobile number
           */
          $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_field', [
              'type' => 'varchar',
              'label' => 'Custom Field',
              'input' => 'text',
              'required' => true,
              'visible' => true,
              'user_defined' => true,
              'sort_order' => 1000,
              'position' => 1000,
              'system' => 0,
          ]);
          //add attribute to attribute set
          $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'mobile_number')
              ->addData([
                  'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                  'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                  'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_create'],
              ]);

          $attribute->save();


      }
  }
```

Now run below command:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

You will see your custom filed in registration form.

Hope this will help you! Thanks.

Comment: You with a custom field is ok. but there are already in the file so I just need to display. So let me know that solutions.